# Updating software during windows restart

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need a way to update my software before(not after) windows restart time.
Scenario:

1. User push shutdown/restart button
2. OS shuting down.
3. Then my installer starts and user can sees message "Updating software" while installer works. So behavior must be similar to windows updates.
4. Windows restarting

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Only the operating system needs to do this. Why do you feel the need to do it?

Comment: Windows will forcibly kill your process if it takes too long to exit during shutdown. You only have a few seconds to do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Our software requires a system restart after update. Not always, but when net driver version is increased it happens. So in current realisation we lose RDP connection in update time and after update user see annoying messages "restart your pc..". We want to get rid of these problems.

Comment: Sounds to me like you should be asking about your problem rather than asking about your solution

Comment: _"...annoying messages "restart your pc..". We want to get rid of these problems"_. Which problems? When the PC need to be restarted it needs to be restarted. If the user doesn't want to restart immediately, he just needs to answer "no" to the question "restart your pc..." or whatever.